# AKS: Kubernetes Pod volume mounting failing even after PV is bound and attached to pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy pod with file mount to azure file share, it seems to bound just fine, but does not mount on the container - could i get some help to make it mount please

I create secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic azstorage-secret --from-literal=azurestorageaccountname=$AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --from-literal=azurestorageaccountkey=$STORAGE_KEY -n large-agents
```

my conatiners:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: linuxbuildagent-large 
  namespace: agents-large
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: "azdevops-agent-sv"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azdevops-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azdevops-agent
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selfhosted-agents
          ...
          volumeMounts:
          - name: azurefileshare
            mountPath: /angular-cache  
          securityContext:
            privileged: true  
      volumes:
      - name: azurefileshare
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-azurefile
```

my persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-azurefile
  namespace: agents-large
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain  # if set as "Delete" file share would be removed in pvc deletion
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  csi:
    driver: file.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: azureBuildClient  # make sure this volumeid is unique in the cluster
    volumeAttributes:
      storageAccount: EXISTING_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
      shareName: longtestshare
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: azstorage-secret
      namespace: agents-large
```

my pv claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-azurefile
  namespace: agents-large
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  volumeName: pv-azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

pv bound in aks cluster:
[image]

pv claims bound in aks cluster:
[image]

Events in describe pod:

```
    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
    Events:
      Type     Reason       Age                 From     Message
      ----     ------       ----                ----     -------
      Warning  FailedMount  38m (x19 over 88m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[azurefileshare], unattached volumes=[docker-graph-storage azurefileshare kube-api-access-cx6tn]: timed out waiting for the condition
      Warning  FailedMount  24m (x6 over 66m)   kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pv-azurefile" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(azureBuildClient) mount //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32
    Mounting command: mount
    Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o dir_mode=0777,actimeo=30,mfsymlinks,file_mode=0777,<masked> //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount
    Output: mount error(2): No such file or directory
    Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
      Warning  FailedMount  20m (x5 over 86m)    kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[azurefileshare], unattached volumes=[azurefileshare kube-api-access-cx6tn docker-graph-storage]: timed out waiting for the condition
      Warning  FailedMount  5m3s (x31 over 90m)  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pv-azurefile" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(azureBuildClient) mount //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32
    Mounting command: mount
    Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,actimeo=30,mfsymlinks,<masked> //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount
    Output: mount error(2): No such file or directory
    Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

kubectl get events in namespace:

```
28m         Warning   FailedMount   pod/linuxbuildagent-large-0   MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pv-azurefile" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(azureBuildClient) mount //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32...
2m46s       Warning   FailedMount   pod/linuxbuildagent-large-0   Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[azurefileshare], unattached volumes=[docker-graph-storage azurefileshare kube-api-access-cx6tn]: timed out waiting for the condition
13m         Warning   FailedMount   pod/linuxbuildagent-large-0   MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pv-azurefile" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(azureBuildClient) mount //crbbroakspersistentstg.file.core.windows.net/longtestshare on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pv-azurefile/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32...
7m19s       Warning   FailedMount   pod/linuxbuildagent-large-0   Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[azurefileshare], unattached volumes=[azurefileshare kube-api-access-cx6tn docker-graph-storage]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have enabled the BLOB CSI Driver.

```
az aks update --enable-blob-driver -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup
```

See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-blob-csi?tabs=NFS